# InvalidateQuery is not automatically updating the state and ui

Tags: reactjs, react-query, state-management

This is a personal budget handler, when you setup a budget you are able to assign expenses to that budget and if you delete it (the budget) and there are expenses in it, it will assign an uncategorized id to those expenses. This is the function that does that:

```
function deleteBudget(id) {
    const previousExpenses = queryClient.getQueryData(["expenses"]);
    deleteBudgetMutation.mutate(id);
    return previousExpenses.expenses.map((expense) => {
      if (expense.budgetId !== id) {
        return expense;
      }
      updateExpenseMutation.mutate({
        id: expense._id,
        data: {
          ...expense,
          budgetId: UNCATEGORIZED_BUDGET,
        },
      });
    });
```

It does assign the uncategorized id to each expense but for some reason it will not update in the ui unless I refresh or change screen.

This is the hook:

```
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

function useUpdateRequest(url, onSuccess, onError, onMutate) {
  const updateExpenseMutation = useMutation(
    async ({ id, data }) => {
      const response = await axios.put(`${url}/${id}`, data);
      return response;
    },
    { onSuccess: onSuccess },
    { onError: onError },
    { onMutate: onMutate }
  );

  return updateExpenseMutation;
}

export default useUpdateRequest;
```

This is how I'm using the hook

```
const updateExpenseMutation = useUpdateRequest(
    "api/expenses",
    {
      onSettled: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["expenses"]);
      },
      onMutate: async (expense) => {
        const previousExpenses = queryClient.getQueryData(["expenses"]);
        await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ["expenses"] });
        queryClient.setQueryData(
          ["expenses"],
          [
            ...previousExpenses,
            {
              description: expense?.description,
              amount: expense?.amount,
              budgetId: expense?.budgetId,
              createdBy: expense?.createdBy,
            },
          ]
        );
        return { previousExpenses };
      },
      onError: () => {
        const previousBudgets = queryClient.getQueryData(["budgets"]);
        queryClient.setQueryData(["budgets", previousBudgets]);
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was.

I was sending an object instead of functions to the hook or in other words sending functions as a value of the given function key (onSuccess, onError, etc) which could be done but had to destructure the functions from the object.

Here are both scenarios:

1. Sending the functions in an object (as I was doing it)

```
const updateExpenseMutation = useUpdateRequest(
    "api/expenses",
    //This is the object
     {
    //Key-value pair
onSettled: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["expenses"]);
      },
      onMutate: async (expense) => {
        const previousExpenses = queryClient.getQueryData(["expenses"]);
        await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ["expenses"] });
        queryClient.setQueryData(
          ["expenses"],
          [
            ...previousExpenses,
            {
              description: expense?.description,
              amount: expense?.amount,
              budgetId: expense?.budgetId,
              createdBy: expense?.createdBy,
            },
          ]
        );
        return { previousExpenses };
      },
      onError: () => {
        const previousBudgets = queryClient.getQueryData(["budgets"]);
        queryClient.setQueryData(["budgets", previousBudgets]);
      },
    }
  );
```

So that means that I had to destructure the functions from the object in the hook like this:

```
function useUpdateRequest(url, { onSuccess, onError, onMutate }) {
  const updateExpenseMutation = useMutation(
    async ({ id, data }) => {
      const response = await axios.put(`${url}/${id}`, data);
      return response;
    },
    { onSuccess: onSuccess },
    { onError: onError },
    { onMutate: onMutate }
  );

  return updateExpenseMutation;
}

export default useUpdateRequest;
```

2. Sending the just functions

```
const updateExpenseMutation = useUpdateRequest(
    "api/expenses",
 function onSettled() {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["expenses"]);
      },
    async function onMutate(expense) {
        const previousExpenses = queryClient.getQueryData(["expenses"]);
        await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ["expenses"] });
        queryClient.setQueryData(
          ["expenses"],
          [
            ...previousExpenses,
            {
              description: expense?.description,
              amount: expense?.amount,
              budgetId: expense?.budgetId,
              createdBy: expense?.createdBy,
            },
          ]
        );
        return { previousExpenses };
      },
      function onError(){
        const previousBudgets = queryClient.getQueryData(["budgets"]);
        queryClient.setQueryData(["budgets", previousBudgets]);
      },
)
```

without having to destructure the functions:

```
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

function useUpdateRequest(url, onSuccess, onError, onMutate ) {
  const updateExpenseMutation = useMutation(
    async ({ id, data }) => {
      const response = await axios.put(`${url}/${id}`, data);
      return response;
    },
    { onSuccess: onSuccess },
    { onError: onError },
    { onMutate: onMutate }
  );

  return updateExpenseMutation;
}

export default useUpdateRequest;
```